# With TypeScript, can I type a curried version of getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>

Tags: typescript, generics, currying

Example from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

```
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, name: K): T[K] {
    return o[name]; // o[name] is of type T[K]
}
```

Curried version:

```
function curriedGetProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(name: K): (o: T) => T[K] {
    return (o: T) => o[name]; // o[name] is of type T[K]
}

const record = { id: 4, label: 'hello' }

const getId = curriedGetProperty('id') // Argument of type '"id"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

const id = getId(record)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type WithProp<T extends any, K extends string> = { [P in K]: T[P] }

function curriedGetProperty <P extends string>(prop: P) {
  return <T, O extends WithProp<T, typeof prop>>(o: O) => {
    return o[prop]
  }
}
```

Seems to type it safer.

```
const getId = curriedGetProperty('id')
getId({id: 'foo'}) // returns string
getId({label: 'hello'}) // fails
```

Comment: However, this does not work with `Partial`. Unless you make `WithProp` like `Partial` by adding a `?` before the `:`

Comment: This allows `getId({})` which returns `any`. But does not allow `getId(43434)` or `getId(null)`

Comment: I think this is about the same as mine, although yours does not require a second step so this may actually be better. You said it allows `getId({})` but for me it does not. And you said it does not allow `getId(null)` but for me it does. I don't think you can avoid being able to pass `null` or `undefined` without enabling strict null checking. Yours also doesn't bind to a particular type `T` until you use it, which makes the property getter usable with strong typing on any object which is also better. This is now the best answer.

Comment: Yeah, I do have `strictNullChecks` enabled for my project

Answer (score 3):

**Edit for TypeScript >= 4.1.5**

```
const makeGetter = <TKey extends string>(key: TKey) => <TObject extends { [P in TKey]?: unknown }>(object: TKey extends keyof TObject ? TObject : `${TKey} is missing as property of object`) => (object as TObject)[key];

const getId = makeGetter('id');

const a: unknown = getId({})
const b: number = getId({id: 1})
const c: number | undefined = getId({} as { id?: number})
```

The compiler will complain about `getId({})` with a helpful error message.

---

Using TypeScript `3.0.3` I was able to do this:

```
function composeGetter<K extends string>(prop: K) {
    function getter<T extends { [P in K]?: any }>(object: T): T[typeof prop]
    function getter<T extends { [P in K]: any }>(object: T) {
        return object[prop]
    }

    return getter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const getProperty = <P extends string>(prop: P) => <O extends any>(obj: O) => obj[prop]

const record = { id: 4, label: 'hello' }

const getId = getProperty('id')

const id = getId(record)
```

This seems to work. The type for `id` is inferred properly as a number. Only thing is you'll receive `any` if the object passed into `getId` doesn't have an `id` property on it, so it's not strict, but an overall elegant solution.

EDIT: Since writing this answer, I've learned that the `Record` type can be used to specify a type of object which requires a specific key. Using this knowledge, we can write a typesafe, succinct, readable solution:

```
// implementation
const get = <K extends string>(key: K) => <V>(obj: Record<K, V>) => obj[key]

// usage
const person = {
  name: "kingdaro",
  age: 21,
}

const fruit = {
  type: "apple",
  color: "red",
}

const nameGetter = get("name")

nameGetter(person) // return type inferred as string
nameGetter(fruit) // fails, fruit has no key "name"

// minor caveat: when passing an object literal, the extra key will raise an error
// you can declare the object separately to sidestep around this
// but this wouldn't come up often anyway
nameGetter({ name: "kingdaro", age: 21 })
```

Comment: This completely bypasses the type system. You can now call it on any object, whether it has the right properties or not. You might as well not be using TypeScript in the first place.

Comment: Not exactly @dave-cousineau. Yes, you can pass anything to `getId`. However the result will be typed accordingly. If you pass `getId({})` you will get `any`. However if you pass `getId({id: 4})` the result will be typed as a number. Or if if you pass `getId({id: undefined} as Partial<{id: number}>)` you will get `number | undefined`

Comment: @chautelly `getId` can be called with anything, but `getProperty` can be called with anything, too. it does return the right type when used correctly though.

Comment: Using the answer by @kingdaro, `getId(reocrd)` returns a `number` type for me

Answer (score 1):

If you split it into a two-step process, it can be minimally verbose and completely type safe at the same time:

```
interface recordType {
   id: number,
   label: string
}

const record = { id: 4, label: 'hello' };

const getPropertyBuilder = function <T>() {
   return <K extends keyof T>(key: K) => (o: T) => o[key];
};

const propertyBuilder = getPropertyBuilder<recordType>();
const getId = propertyBuilder('id'); // getId is (o: recordType) => number
const id = getId(record); // id is number

// or in one go
const label = getPropertyBuilder<recordType>()('label')(record); // label is string
```

Also works with `Partial` as mentioned:

```
const propertyBuilder = getPropertyBuilder<Partial<typeof record>>();
const getId = propertyBuilder('id');
const id = getId(record); // id is number
const id2 = getId({ id: 3 }); // also number
```

Comment: Yeah, that works as well. Except that `getId` is now less flexible. I wouldn't be able to pass `Partial<typeof record>`

Comment: Also, `function curriedGetProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(name: K) {` has to be typed this way and `const getId = curriedGetProperty<Rec, 'id'>('id');`. Otherwise the result of `getId` is `number | string`

Comment: @chautelly it doesn't seem possible to avoid the type being `string | number`, even with `K`

Comment: It does work for me. Are you calling `curriedGetProperty` like this: `curriedGetProperty<Rec, 'id'>('id');`

Comment: ok yes, you narrowed the type down to just 'id' and that narrowed the result as well.